# MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe EXECUTION FAILURE with "MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist."

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

Our .NET solution is compiling well from `MSBUILD` command line. We're using `MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe` for Sonar Quality metrics which fails with message

> EXECUTION FALIURE" during post processing. Log shows error message as
>   "INFO  - MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.

Tried trace/debug level logging in sonar but nothing useful comes up. Post processing and compilation always succeeds. Only noticable point is that after above error line next line says

> INFO  - Switch:
>   D:\OurProject.sonarqube\out.sonar\q3techAMSUSProducerIVRGallery-Dev_AMSUSProducerIVRGallery_q3techAMSUSProducerIVRGallery-Dev_AMSUSProducerIVRGallery_397A5FDA-B454-4739-9A38-91810B9229DC\StyleCop-msbuild.proj

Reffered stylecop file is present on disk, as well as we've tried disabling all stylecop and fxcop rules but nothing helps. If required log file can be shared.

PLEASE ADVISE - Solution or Diagnosis Steps?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've solved this by bypassing FxCop rules on the project.